# Exasol and ESRI's ArcGIS - anyone managed to link them up?

Tags: geospatial, arcgis, esri, exasolution

I'm looking to utilise the speed of Exasolution with the mapping capabilities of ArcGIS.

Exasolution is an extremely fast database. It has spatial support, but I'd like to be able to render spatial features inside a map. So it could be via some kind of API from Esri, or maybe a third party mapping engine and use WMS/WFS etc.

Anyone had any joy with these products?

Cheers

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is a bit on the broad side. Also, there are only 6 questions tagged with exasolution, so you are asking a very bread question about a very niche product.

Answer (score 0):

You will likely have some joy with EXASolution's JDBC driver - EXASolution's Geospatial libraries are built on OpenGIS using the libGEOS libraries, so everything you can do with Postgres should be possible on EXASolution.

I did an introductory Geospatial-on-EXASOL video a while back which may be of interest https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f6Erp1WWLHw

I would say that your question would get a better response in EXASOL's community section where EXASOL customers and techies can answer specific EXASOL questions. Go to exasol.com/community for more details.

Good luck - and do let me know how you get on

Graham Mossman
Solution Engineer
EXASOL A.G.

Answer (score 0):

I just finished a short knowledge base article which shows you how to connect to ESRI's ArcGIS from within an EXASolution database:
https://www.exasol.com/support/browse/SOL-211

The approach is different from what Graham suggested, as it uses Esri's REST API in combination with Python scripts called from SQL. So, the database connects directly and in parallel to the REST API service, not involving the client at all when it comes to data enrichment.

Hope that helps,
Franz